# Route not restored for alias interface

Tags: debian, ubuntu, networking, iproute

I've this network configuration on a Debian 10 Buster:

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

allow-hotplug enp3s0
iface enp3s0 inet static
        address 192.168.0.175
        netmask 255.255.255.0
        gateway 192.168.0.254
        dns-nameservers 8.8.8.8 8.8.4.4

allow-hotplug enp3s0:1
iface enp3s0:1 inet static
        address 192.168.3.175
        netmask 255.255.255.0
```

It works perfectly, but when making some tests like repeatedly unplugging the network cable and putting back  I'm running into a weird issue: route for the alias interface `:1` is not restored, but IP address is!

To make it short, when I put back the network cable the two IP addresses are configured correctly, but only the `192.168.0.0/24` route is restored.

After reboot everything works fine. This just happens when unplugging network cable. I tried with `auto enp3s0` instead of `allow-hotplug` but behaves the same.

Comment: What routes are you adding? How do they get added to the routing table?

Comment: I'm not adding routes, it's done automatically by `ifupdown` or anyway by networking scripts. The missing route is the one related to the *alias* IP

Comment: Anyway considering alias interfaces are not really interfaces (the kernel sees them as addresses with a label. They can't be used by most tools like iptables nftables etc.) you'd better alter your setting into having an additional IP on the same interface. *Maybe* then the scripts will cope better. Compare [legacy method](https://wiki.debian.org/NetworkConfiguration#Legacy_method) with [iproute2 method](https://wiki.debian.org/NetworkConfiguration#iproute2_method).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out the problem, which wasn't due to the `interfaces` file but a conflict with **wcid**, LXDE network manager. The LAN interface was managed by *both* systems and did get unconfigured on cable disconnect but wasn't on reconnection.

Removing it from wcid restored full functionality.